# In Australia, what does the term "Big polluters" mean?

Tags: terminology, australia

In Australia, does the term "Big Polluters" have any specific meaning?

Here's an example of the phrase being used: [The Dinosaurs, by The Climate Institute](http://youtu.be/gHgRwUJJ0pQ?t=22s)

> Right now, big polluters have to pay for their emissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one specific meaning to the phrase.

The Rudd/Gillard/Rudd Labor government targetted a certain number of companies for a carbon price. From [The great carbon tax secret: who are the Misfortune 500?](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2011-07-12/the-great-carbon-tax-secret-who-are-the-misfortune/2790974)

> So Ms Gillard was exceedingly careful with her pronouns when she
>   addressed the nation. "Around 500 big polluters will pay for every
>   tonne of carbon pollution THEY put into OUR atmosphere," she said
>   (I've added the capitals, not in order to make that quotation look
>   shouty, but to identify the allocation of responsibility the PM's
>   trying to convey here; WE are getting those polluters to pay for what
>   THEY do to US).
>
> Listen to talkback for 30 seconds and you'll pick up what the general
>   presumption is - a sort of vague impression that Big Polluters and Big
>   Business are pretty much the same thing.
>
> But who are these 500 big polluters, exactly - this Misfortune 500,
>   who are to be history's martyrs to the answering of our generation's
>   greatest moral challenge?
>
> Can we get a list?
>
> No - we can't, according to the Government. The 500 companies are not
>   an identified list. The figure of 500 is just an estimate of how many
>   companies in Australia would be caught by the scheme's eligibility
>   rules.

The Climate Institute has a [similar description](http://www.climateinstitute.org.au/carbon-laws-at-work.html):

> 1 July, 2014 marks the second anniversary of the carbon laws – the
>   Clean Energy Act and related laws that price and reduce pollution,
>   invest in renewable energy and support households and business in the
>   shift to a cleaner economy. The laws are working and have delivered
>   impressive results:  Australia’s pollution is down; economic growth is
>   up; unemployment and inflation remains under control; and solar and
>   wind energy has soared.
>
> …
>
> The laws, which began on 1 July 2012, put a limit and price on carbon
>   pollution from Australia's 370 largest emitting entities (large
>   companies and cities/councils). The price is fixed for the first three
>   years, but evolves into an emissions trading scheme on 1 July, 2015.
>
> The laws force Australia’s biggest polluters to take responsibility
>   for their pollution and creates a financial incentive for them to
>   invest in curbing emissions. Revenues raised from the laws is used to
>   help households and businesses adjust to a lower-carbon economy.
>
> The laws also established the independent Climate Change Authority (to
>   give unbiased advice on climate policy) and the Clean Energy Finance
>   Corporation (to break down barriers to investment in low-emissions
>   technologies).